# tomcat7 error when building webapp with maven and intellij 14

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, spring-security, tomcat7, pom.xml

I can't solve the error while building my webapp on localhost. The error code is:

```
 SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component     [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1760)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context  /support/RequestHandledEvent
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2436)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806)
at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:892)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5380)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.support.RequestHandledEvent
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
... 54 more
 2015 1:34:56 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean invoke    SEVERE: Exception invoking method manageApp
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1760)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

 29, 2015 1:34:56 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean invoke
SEVERE: Exception invoking method createStandardContext javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method manageApp
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:309)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1760)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
... 31 more

[2015-01-29 01:34:56,135] Artifact TShips:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details. 
 29, 2015 1:35:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\manager
29, 2015 1:35:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\manager has finished in 654 ms
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\bin\catalina.bat" stop Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\‘ва ­­ЁЄ\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_TShips" Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\apache-tomcat-7.0.57" Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\temp"
 Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
 29, 2015 1:44:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
INFO: A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
  29, 2015 1:44:19 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
 INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
 29, 2015 1:44:19 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
 INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
29, 2015 1:44:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
29, 2015 1:44:19 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
29, 2015 1:44:19 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
29, 2015 1:44:19 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
 29, 2015 1:44:19 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

the web.xml is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Loads Spring Security and other config files -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>


<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

and pom.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>TShips</groupId>
  <artifactId>tships</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


 <properties>
  <java.version>1.7</java.version>
  <spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
  <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
  <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
  <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
  <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
  <slf4j.version>1.7.6</slf4j.version>
  <hibernate.version>4.2.11.Final</hibernate.version>
  <dbcp.version>1.4</dbcp.version>
  <servletapi.version>2.5</servletapi.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
<!-- database pool -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
  <version>${dbcp.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate ORM -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate validation -->

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- EL -->

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring core & mvc -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


<!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- jstl for jsp page -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>jstl</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>${jstl.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- MySQL Driver -->

<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.34</version>
</dependency>

<!-- CGLib for @Configuration -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>cglib</groupId>
  <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
  <version>${cglib.version}</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Java Mail API -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- logging, slf4j -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <version>${logback.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Bootstrap & jquery -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>


<!-- Servlet -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>${servletapi.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency> 
  </dependencies>
 <repositories>
   <repository>
     <id>springsource-milestones</id>
         <name>SpringSource Milestones Proxy</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/springsource-milestones</url>
      </repository> 
    <repository>
     <id>JBoss repository</id>
     <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
   </repository>
 </repositories>
<build>
   <finalName>tships</finalName>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.2</version>
         <configuration>
         <source>${java.version}</source>
         <target>${java.version}</target>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
   </plugins>
```

The target folder structure is like:

- classes
  -- orm
  -- tships
  --logback.xml
- generated-sources
  -- annotations
- tships
  -- meta-inf
  -- web-inf
- war
- manifest

spring-security.xml, spring-databse.xml and mvc-dispatcher-servlet are in WEB-INF directory. If needed, I can give more info and post other parts. It seems for me that there is some issue in building the project, but can't figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your log the line:

**Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context  /support/RequestHandledEvent**

You need to add another dependency in your pom.xml

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
<version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
```

Comment: thank you, I thought about this line, but didn't understand what does it want. but unfrortunately with this dependancy included it gives just the same exception...

Comment: now I'm getting some progress. I also added this jar into WEB-INF/lib, with other spring dependencies. now it returned org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-database.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource  . perhaps I must add all jars there

Comment: Well, it gives yet another stack trace, which may refer to hibernate configuration. 
" DEBUG o.h.internal.SessionFactoryImpl - HHH000031: Closing
11:08:23.492 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'dataSource'
[2015-01-29 11:08:23,709] Artifact TShips:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details. " - this is in the end. maybe you have got any ideas, why?

Comment: Your problem is related to missing classes in classpath.
ClassNotFoundException: class didn't exist on the classpath.
NoClassDefFoundError: class was at compile time but not available at runtime
I can see that you use properties in your pom and then you use differents version, for instance,
spring-context-support you are using 4.0.8 but you use spring with version 3.2.8. Review every dependency and make sure
you are not mixing versions.

Comment: should all versions be the same? for instance, if spring mvc is 3.2.8, then security also 3.2.8. and context-support etc.? I will look into it, thank you!

Comment: check versions here:http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework and http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config. Besides you can open your pom with eclipse and go Dependency Hierarchy tab to see the dependencies (or use command mvn dependency:tree) Also have a look:http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-with-maven, can give you an idea of how it's done

Comment: done, I've updates spring to 4.1.4.RELEASE. but it now gives me just "Error during artifact deployment" without any clues about what's wrong. Only this: "DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] threw NamingException with message: Name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain].. Returning null."  I looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750619/spring-jndi-namingexception-name-spring-livebeansview-mbeandomain-is-not-boun , but the solution didn't help either

Comment: could you share your whole application by ftp, git or whatever you like?

Comment: thank you; I will send it to you in a while. right now after some cleaning (I've got DelegatingFilterProxy twice in my web.xml - that could be the issue), I am facing another one:   "NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2:  conferenceServiceImpl,ConferenceServiceImpl" and watching similar reports, but, yeah, I have only ConferenceServiceImpl, declared in my spring-database.xml. I will send it soon

Comment: here it is (I've rewritten a new project, but it returns the same):
web.xml: http://pastebin.com/Wd67ydig
spring-security.xml: http://pastebin.com/RBtHEDrH
spring-database.xml: http://pastebin.com/5JQXUMEX
mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml: http://pastebin.com/5adWLrXr
pom.xml: http://pastebin.com/5sGw4XPe
HomeController: http://pastebin.com/1XDWQUDH
Conference (model): http://pastebin.com/StuW0S7f
ConfererenceDaoImpl (dao): http://pastebin.com/F3Xv6ACE
ConferenceServiceImpl (service): http://pastebin.com/96uQMmAx
Other DAO-s and Services are in many ways similar

Comment: And the whole project looks like: http://s010.radikal.ru/i312/1502/a7/4b55e26233db.jpg

Comment: P.S. "spring-profile-active" was taken from solutions here, but didn't help -since I don't have andy dev+prod profiles, I've got only a default one

Comment: The configuration is ok. I packaged with Intellij and deployed in tomcat 7. 
Work perfectly. As I have touched small things, I left code,dump and tomcat with the aplication in this directory.
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6S-gUp00eJzX01QUjVfSTRQckU&usp=sharing
Compare your war with mine because maybe your package is not ok. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you. It seems like war. My whole app is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByHcTuwAj7LpalBrTXJFZHBnZ1k/view?usp=sharing  
Strangely, it doesn't want to be modified or rebuilt. But I will try though

Comment: I´m still thinking you are doing something wrong when you make the package, because in your
project I can see wrong things. Try this,take the project I have just letf "TallinkShips-TRY-THIS.zip" and package using maven with commands: mvn clean and then mvn package, then deploy the war in your tomcat. Project is here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6S-gUp00eJzRUJZSlpvemdCckU&usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you. But why intelliJ does things like this (in my example)? I didn't do anything, just standard build and here it results...

Comment: I made my package with Intellij, I used Run Goal command.
I told you to use  mvn from the command line to see the configuration is ok. Your problem is that you package wrong with intellij.
Have a look the documentation how to do it https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/maven.html