# Parallel Deployment Exception

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, deployment, parallel-processing

when I deploy a new version (3.0.1) of my webapp on Tomcat 8 [on tomcat is deployed an older version (3.0.0)] i get this exception:

Failed to register LiveBeansView MBean; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to register LiveBeansView MBean; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: security-base,security-api:application=/MyWebApplication
>       at org.springframework.context.support.LiveBeansView.registerApplicationContext(LiveBeansView.java:72)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:776)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:473)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1617)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>       at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1483)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:731)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:424)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:589)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: security-base,security-api:application=/MyWebApplication
>       at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
>       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
>       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
>       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
>       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
>       at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.LiveBeansView.registerApplicationContext(LiveBeansView.java:68)
>       ... 51 more

In web.xml of my application i have this configuration:

```
<context-param>  
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>  
    <param-value>security-base,security-api</param-value>  
</context-param>  
<context-param>  
    <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>  
    <param-value>security-base,security-api</param-value>  
</context-param>
<context-param>  
    <param-name>spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain</param-name>  
    <param-value>security-base,security-api</param-value>  
</context-param>
```

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have **two** deployments on your Tomcat server for the **same** application (albeit different versions), you'll need to name your MBeans differently. Since MBeans are accessed per server (via a single JMX endpoint), each MBean identifier has to be separate.

You have a few options to make these unique in your apps:

1. The simplest solution is to set `endpoints.jmx.unique-names` to `true` and let [Spring Boot make the MBean paths unique for you](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html), rather than using default names.
   .
2. Alternatively, you can change the MBean domain by setting the`spring.jmx.default-domain=applicationname` for the application
3. And you might likely not need this, but adding here for completeness; if you're manually loading your beans in Spring Configuration, you can add the `EnableMBeanExport` specifying a domain as such:

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableMBeanExport(defaultDomain="first")
   public class MBeanConfig {...}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In my application 'spring.profiles' were added to get rid of debug log. [spring jndi NamingException: Name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] is not bound in this Context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750619/spring-jndi-namingexception-name-spring-livebeansview-mbeandomain-is-not-boun)
I fixed this issue by modifying web.xml for each deployed application making param-value  unique per web.xml.

<param-value>***prod***</param-value>

vs

<param-value>***test***</param-value>

For example:

Production:

```
  <context-param>  
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>  
    <param-value>prod</param-value>  
  </context-param>  
  <context-param>  
    <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>  
    <param-value>prod</param-value>  
  </context-param>
  <context-param>  
    <param-name>spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain</param-name>  
    <param-value>prod</param-value>  
  </context-param>
```

Testing

```
  <context-param>  
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>  
    <param-value>test</param-value>  
  </context-param>  
  <context-param>  
    <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>  
    <param-value>test</param-value>  
  </context-param>
  <context-param>  
    <param-name>spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain</param-name>  
    <param-value>test</param-value>  
  </context-param>
```